# PHP: Match duplicate text rows while ignoring some prefix

Tags: php, duplicates

My text (`...` is actual part of it):

```
(01) Text here
(02) sometimes also (with brackets)
(03) foo
(05) and [other stuff!?]
...
(07) foo
(08) bar
(09) bar
```

Find duplicate rows `(XX) foo` and `(XX) bar` and print them.

```
//workaround
$tNormalized = preg_replace('/(*ANYCRLF)^\(\d+\) /m', '(??) ', $t);

$arr = explode("\n", $tNormalized);
if ( count($arr) > 1 )  {
    for ($i=1; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
        if( $arr[$i-1] == $arr[$i] ) {
            echo "Match:<br>";
            echo $arr[$i-1];
            echo $arr[$i];
        }
  }
}
```

Desired result:

```
Match:
(03) foo
(07) foo

Match:
(08) bar
(09) bar
```

- <strike>Problem 1</strike>: Match duplicate rows while ignoring the numbers in the brackets at the beginning of the rows. I want to print the numbers in brackets. Normalizing them to "(??)" is just a workaround.
- <strike>Problem 2</strike>: `if( $arr[$i-1] == $arr[$i] )`: This checks the previous row. But also check `$arr[$i-2]`, `$arr[$i-3]` etc.

Test: http://codepad.viper-7.com/4IQV8x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your regexp, You don't need that any CRLF at the beggining.

`preg_replace('/^\(\d+\) /m', '(??) ', $t);`

You can sort the array before cycle, so that checking items that are besides each other will be enough.

`sort($arr);`

Comment: Thanks. `sort($arr);` is a great help.